# Android. Рисование прямоугольника в левом верхнем углу видимой части canvas

Tags: android, canvas

Как нарисовать прямоугольник в левом верхнем углу видимой части Canvas?
Сейчас верхнюю грань перекрывает Action Bar, поэтому рисуемую фигуру не видно.
Как вариант можно узнать высоту Action Bar и рисовать относительно неё, но хотелось бы узнать есть ли возможность сразу установить начало координат в видимую часть canvas (не перекрываемую action bar'ом).